# Spline wrap animation

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, splines

I want to create in blender an animation similar with this one:
[image]

I am wondering how could I do and if it possible to interact with rigid body objects?
Who can help me, please ... thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The object could be a simple (say) Bezier curve, with a Bevel Object (another curve) assigned to it in its Properties > Geometry panel.

The 'Tilt' property of *individual* control points on a Bezier curve is keyable:

[image]

So just right-click it to set keyframes appropriately.. if you want a loop, set first and last keys to be visually identical, and go into the property's f-Curve, hit <kbd>T</kbd>, and ensure that the interpolation between the keys is 'Linear'.

[image]

Comment: or, to make a loop you can just tilt 10° or whatever, then, in the Dopesheet or Graph Editor, shift E > Linear Extrapolation

Comment: I am wondering if it is possible to make it dynamic rigid body animated, to interact with other objects?

Comment: @diniulian   I'm pretty sure that would work, if instead of a pure curve, you used a star-prism _mesh_ with a curve modifier.. you could still animate the twist on the modifier's target curve. But I can't make that an answer until I've checked it.. I'll let you know, if you don't get there first. Perhaps to get good exposure, that should be another question?

Comment: @diniulian    No Luck :(  in 279 I have not so far  managed to get Physics to recognize the Curve modifier, despite collisions being set to 'Final', which should take all modifiers into account and even the curve being explicitly included in the Physics World group It could still be me.. maybe this would be worth another question.

Comment: @diniulian please make a new question for the rigid body part. That was not part of the original question. Don't make the Comments section a new "thread". This is not a forum, but a question and answer site. Help us keep things organized, and help other users access the information in an easier way.